# when I run redis-stack-server,redis-stack config file is not work

Tags: redis, redis-stack

I installed redis-stack on Ubuntu20. I changed redis-stack.conf but it not work.I changed daemonize to yes but it not work.

this is log when I run redis-stack-server

````
    root@Server-30c80333-7b1b-40ce-a1e2-217630a6941b:~# redis-stack-server
Starting redis-stack-server, database path /var/lib/redis-stack
3601:C 03 Jun 2022 01:37:09.809 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
3601:C 03 Jun 2022 01:37:09.809 # Redis version=7.0.0, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=3601, just started
3601:C 03 Jun 2022 01:37:09.809 # Configuration loaded
3601:M 03 Jun 2022 01:37:09.810 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
                _._                                                  
           _.-``__ ''-._                                             
      _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 7.0.0 (00000000/0) 64 bit
  .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._                                  
 (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in standalone mode
 |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|     Port: 6379
 |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 3601
  `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-'                                   
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           https://redis.io       
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |                                  
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
      `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'                                       
          `-._        _.-'                                           
              `-.__.-'
````

this is config I read from redis-client

```
127.0.0.1:6379> info server
# Server
redis_version:7.0.0
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:23cf6761424b731f
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 5.4.0-100-generic x86_64
arch_bits:64
monotonic_clock:POSIX clock_gettime
multiplexing_api:epoll
atomicvar_api:c11-builtin
gcc_version:9.4.0
process_id:3601
process_supervised:no
run_id:4c157cf9e719b8afeb43fdbcbd11873448e650ac
tcp_port:6379
server_time_usec:1654191533516795
uptime_in_seconds:104
uptime_in_days:0
hz:10
configured_hz:10
lru_clock:10024365
executable:/opt/redis-stack/bin/redis-server
config_file:/opt/redis-stack/etc/redis-stack.conf
io_threads_active:0
127.0.0.1:6379> config get daemonize
1) "daemonize"
2) "no"
127.0.0.1:6379> exit
```

I find redis-stack.conf in config_file path, but I can not find redis-config file in anywhere.
I want to change the daemonize to yes but I can't find redis-config file.

Comment: "it not work" isn't a clear description of a failure. Please [edit] the question and tell us what you want to do, show what you tried, and show what unexpected results you got.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a config file present in /opt/redis-stack/etc/.